# How to check a log of stored procedure calls?

Tags: sql-server

Is there some type of logging in SQL Server (or some way to enable simple logging) that would allow me to check if a stored procedure was called, when it was called, and what parameters were passed and returned?  I have seen some addon scripts for this but wasn't sure if this was built into SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the SQL Server Profiler tool:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: Through this we can capture the event logs but I believe we can't capture the "print logs" of the called stored procedure.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't built in

You need to set up a [profiler trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx) or add code to your stored procedures to log

Answer (score 6):

There is not much built in for this. If you are using recent versions of SQL Server (your question is not very precise on this point), you can look at [the DMV sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx), but it will not have individual calls, just aggregates.

If you are interested in a particular stored procedure, you could run a very targeted <s>[server-side trace](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/The_Server-side_Trace:_What,_Why,_and_How)</s> [server-side trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx). (Sorry, since Quest decided to kill SQLServerPedia, I can't find the original post I referenced).

I wrote an article about building your own logging and adding it to n stored procedures:

- [Simple process to track and log SQL Server stored procedure use](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

You could easily expand that to include the parameters called.